# Consuming REST service with basic authentication from MULE

Tags: mule, integration, mule-studio, mule-component

i am using HTTP component of mule to connect to a REST API which is having a basic Authentication with USERNAME and PASSWORD . I used  "HTTP settings" tab of HTTP component to supply the authentication details , username and Password. but i think its not working .
Am i doing anything wrong ? is there any better way to call REST service which is having Basic authentication like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the Basic Authentication value as a Header Property in to the outgoing Mule Message when you are consuming a REST service via the Mule HTTP outbound endpoint.

```
<flow name="consume_rest">
    .............
    ..........
    <set-property propertyName="Authorization" value="Basic Authorization String combination of Username and password" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" responseTimeout="20000"
        host="localhost" path="rest.path" port="Port number" />
    .............
    .............
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of REST Service with Basic Authentication :-

```
  <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="your username" password="your password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                     <ss:user name="your username2" password="your password2" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>    
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="MainService" doc:name="MainService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP">
           <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="realm" />
           <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>  <!-- Restrict a particular group of users -->
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

And for connecting an existing external REST Service from Mule use:- `http://username:password@host/yourpath` in http outbound endpoint

Comment: i have done the same thing as you have mentioned in the snippet and i am using the same URL format to consume the service from any client including  mule HTTP . However , i would like to use the existing MULE HTTP component and the basic authentication option within "Advanced tab " so that will mention the username and the password in the component itself and i will use the normal url which will not contain the authentication details.

Comment: This is simple ... In http outbound endpoint in HTTP Settings tab you will find the option of username and password ... so, In the advance tab you just put the url in the address section and then in the HTTP Settings tab put you username and password ... So finally your xml would look like :- `<https:outbound-endpoint address="you url" user="youruser" password="your password" exchange-pattern="request-response" method=""`  and yes check the method in outbound endpoint .. Select be either GET or POST as per your REST Service

Comment: Mule works fine with the url http://username:password@host/yourpath which contains the authentication  credentials .
 However , I tried in the same way as you mentioned above .I mean setting the username and password in the Mule connector but it throws the folowing error 
Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. 
Authentication denied on endpoint URL Message payload is of type: String

Comment: That's Strange ... It should be something like :-  `<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"  user="your username" password="your password" port="your port" path="yourpath" doc:name="HTTP" method="Your method"/>`  .. Pls check the **method** ... by default Http outbound method is POST .. Check with your REST service .. put the method that your webservice is using POST/GET/PUT etc .. better update your question with your Mule XML .. it will e easy for us to detect the issue ...

Comment: Ok .. Try the following .. this will work .. put **host** , **port** and **path** in place of **address** like the following  :-  `<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"  user="username" password="password" port="Your Port" path="your path" doc:name="HTTP" method="GET"/>` ... This way you can put **username** and **password** in **httpoutbound endpoint**

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP outbound with basic authentication](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/consuming-rest-service-with-basic-authentication-from-mule?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=15166052#reply_15166052)

Thanks everyone for replying !! 
The username and password on the connector is for when you want to secure your inbound endpoint with HTTP basic authentication.

When calling a external services that is secured with basic auth you should use the uri method